# How To convert a number in a string into a list with every number is alone

Tags: python, string, list, input, output

i wanted to make a code which you put a random number using **Input** **(Should be more than two dights)**
and the program make it a list which is every dight alone, or with more precise **I wont to spell the numbers**

i've tried this and i don't found any solution

Ex of what i want to do:

```
input = "57472"
output = [5, 7, 4, 7, 2]
```

Comment: `list(map(int, "57472"))` ?

Comment: Use a for loop in a  list comprehension.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I suggest you post what you have tried.

Comment: `[int(x) for x in inp]`? *Never* use `input` as variable name, as it possibly overwrites the `input` method!

Comment: i have tried list(map(int, "57472")) and it work !

Answer (score 0):

A simple **[int(x) for x in input]** would do, if I understand the question correctly.

For list comprehension, look at eg: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`m_list = input.split('')`

It will split the string into it's chars, if you want the elements to be int just convert each of them